# Establishing a Connection Asynchronously

Tags: java, javafx

I was told to run all of my MySQL connection processes on another thread besides the main thread to avoid the main thread from being stuck on a process that takes a few seconds to process.

Therefore, I established a ConnectionPool in a separate thread, so that my GUI launches independently from the establishment of the connection. **However, this is not the case. When I run the program, it waits until the connection is established and then it actually runs launch(args);** My concern is why is it not running independently when a new thread is being established?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    initiateConnection();
    launch(args);
}

private static void initiateConnection() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            connection = new ConnectionPool("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.0/comm", "root",
                    "pass");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }).run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Javadocs of Thread.run()

> If this thread was constructed using a separate Runnable run object, then that Runnable object's run method is called; otherwise, this method does nothing and returns.

So, only the body of lambda expression (which is actually body of the method `run` of `java.lang.Runnable` ) is called. It is equivalent to:

```
    (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                connection = new ConnectionPool("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.0/comm", "root",
                        "pass");
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }).run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `.start()` instead of `.run()`. The JVM will call `.run` on your lambda for you.

Comment: What is the difference between the two of them?

Comment: `.start` actually causes the thread to begin execution (aka run asynchronously, by spawning a thread and calling `.run` in that thread); `.run` is a synchronous operation.